# Is there something similar to OS Python library for executing commands on Oracle NoSql Database?

Tags: python, bash, oracle, nosql, oracle-nosql

I am new to using Oracle NoSql database. I am trying to save tweets in an API.Table from a JSON file.

The API.Table is an abstraction that allows you to use a similar schema as a relational database. I have successfully created the table, and I have also successfully stored the 126 tweets in it from a JSON file using the following command:

```
put table -name table_name -file ./tweets.json
```

I have a Python script that collects the tweets from streaming and stores them in the JSON file, and I use the "os" library to call the command that allows me to enter in the kv bash.

```
import os
os.system("java -jar lib/kvstore.jar runadmin -host kvlite -port 5000 -store kvstore")
```

Now, the script prompts the kv bash just fine, the problem comes with this line of code:

```
os.system("put table -name table_name -file ./tweets.json")
```

The reason it doesn't work is simple, since the "os" library let's you execute commands on the Linux Bash, but not in the kv bash. Is there anything similar to this line so that I can execute that command on the kv bash?

For reference, I've also attached an image where you can see both terminals. Thank you all in advance.

[image: Both terminals]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this

```
import os
os.system("java -jar lib/kvstore.jar runadmin -host kvlite -port 5000 -store 
kvstore put table -name table_name -file ./tweets.json")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

As I said in the beginning of the question, what you suggested is what I did initially. However, it is not a good approach for the volume of data I am collecting, as I would have to repeat that process over and over again.

I have also taken a look at the API, but nothing else there that solves my problem.

Comment: @AliAs Can you pls following command    import os
os.system("java -jar lib/kvstore.jar runadmin -host kvlite -port 5000 -store kvstore put table -name table_name -file ./tweets.json"). Let me know if that works. I have edited my response above.

Comment: Yup, that absolutely worked. Thank you very much @AAP